# SSR function con control panel

Tags: relay, control, solid-state-relay, basic, interconnect

I'm new in electronics and would like to build an electric brewery with an electronic control panel. I found on www.instructables.com one control panel and is described as in following image.

Could someone recommend me basic literature to start reading on how to make calculations / connection basics, etc?
Why is the SSR connected to the relay (green square on image)?
What is the purpose of that SSR on the given image, couldn't one of the relays be avoided?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a wiring digram instead of a circuit diagram. These are not very easy to read sometimes. If you had a circuit diagram it might be clearer....

Anyway... it looks like the PID controllers are always on so the SSR will always be controlling the heater power circuit (12V, 1A for  example). This is not a good thing when the heaters are not needed.

Instead of switching the PID controllers off the designer has switched the SSR power circuit on or off by using a relay. This is on the power side of the circuit.

The same effect can be achieved by switching the SSR control signal (The SSR LED circuit) or turning the PID Controllers off.

Why switch the power side of the circuit? I can not tell.

A smaller relay (ie a signal relay (5V, 20mA for example) for the SSR control circuit) could have been used instead to save power and expense ...

The likely answer is it is just as easy to do this and or it was a copy of an existing control panel ...

Comment: Having re-read the question I could interpret it as also containing "Why use an SSR instead of a relay?". The SSR has effectively unlimited number of switching cycles. The relay would have to be special to have more than 100,000 cycles. This means you would be replacing it every 2 months or so (They do tend to last longer - sometimes 2 to 3 times as long - but they are only guaranteed 100,000 unless you spend more). To give you an idea if the relay switched 1 time every minute and it’s on for a day then 100,000/(60*24) = approx. 70 days